# Message not showing up in queue(RabbitMQ)

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I am using RabbitMQ to queue up all the messages and send the messages as SMS to respective consumers. I am using a Direct exchange and I have correctly created a binding to a queue with a routing key. The problem is, when I try to publish a message, I get some activity in the Message rates chart, but the message doesn't show up in the queue[image]

Could certainly use some help here. I am sure the binding is done correctly.
Am I missing some other configuration?

Comment: Do you have any consumer which currently consuming the queue?

Comment: We have to trust you when you say you have correctly created queues, bindings and are using the correct routing key, even though the evidence suggests otherwise. Without more details, people are left to guess at what may be going on.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to "use specific exchanges", not sending message without specified exchange. I had same issue, when I published it to `amq.direct` or `amq.fanout` it worked as I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

If your configuration is correct, and you also have an active consumer that listens to that queue, I don't think anything is wrong. Doesn't those metrics depicts that the event was published and then delivered and acknowledged by the consumer ? So of course you won't have any queued events since it was consumed as soon as it was published.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the message is delivered to a consumer (as you can see in the chart). Remove the consumer and try to publish the message again, and you will see that it ends up in the queue instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was creating custom queue so I had to provide custom queue ID as a **routing key**.